# how to get the header info in Netflix DGS resolver

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, netflix, netflix-dgs

We can write the query resolver layer as below

```
@DgsData(parentType = "Query", field = "answersByQuestionUuid")
    public List<Answer> answersByQuestionUuid(@InputArgument("questionUuid") UUID questionUuid,
                                              @InputArgument("enhancedContent") boolean enhancedContent,
                                              @InputArgument("templateName") String templateName)  {
        if (enhancedContent) {
            return getStructuredAnswersByQuestionUUID(questionUuid.toString(), templateName);
        }
        return getAnswersByQuestionUUID(questionUuid);
    }
```

How I can get the HTTP header in the  resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to DGS input arguments, you can use the `@RequestHeader` annotation from the Spring framework to receive HTTP request header values. For example:

```
    public List<Answer> answersByQuestionUuid(@InputArgument("questionUuid") UUID questionUuid,
                                              @RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType)  {
```

Comment: https://netflix.github.io/dgs/datafetching/#requestheader-and-dgsrequestdata